# Arabic cells' tables rendered from right to left

Tags: tables, arabic, right-to-left

Is there a way to get arabic cells' tables rendered from right to left just like they are typesetted.
here is a minimal example!

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[ utf8 ]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}

\usepackage[arabic]{babel} 

\usepackage{array}

\newsavebox{\RTLbox}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\RTLbox}}c<{\end{lrbox}\AR{\usebox{\RTLbox}}}}

\begin{document}

أ ب ت

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tabular}{*{3}R}
أ & ب & ت
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you using [`polyglossia`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) and change to `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` engine.

`polyglossia`  re­lies on the `fontspec` pack­age to manipulate fonts, and `bidi` to change direction of text from right to left (arabic script).

You can insert tabular in RTL mode, or in LTR mode depending on context.

---

**MWE**

```
% compile with xelatex 
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri} % font for arabic text 
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}

أ ب ت

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{*{3}c}
أ & ب & ت
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{english}

\begin{tabular}{*{3}c}
a & b & c
\end{tabular}

\end{english}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there any solution in latex ? How to install xelatex

Comment: `XeLaTeX` is included by default in `miktex`.

Comment: and what about texlive ? I am on linux!

Comment: xetex is available on texlive. so it is ok

Answer (score 0):

You defined a new kind of column `R` with:

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\RTLbox}}c<{\end{lrbox}\AR{\usebox{\RTLbox}}}}
```

but you don't use it since you use the `c` type of column in your document.

Try to use `\begin{tabular}{*{3}R}`, it should be better.

Comment: yes it is a mistake so I correct it